# Angular seo hashPrefix('!') google and yandex indexation

Tags: angularjs

friends, can anybody help.
Angular 1.4.9 make links like this **http://domain/#!/product**,
but I need links like this **http://domain/#!product** with out slash.
Code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute'
])
.config([
    '$routeProvider',
    '$locationProvider',
    function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, ngMeta) {
        'use strict';
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                controller: 'HomeCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
            })
            .when('/article/:slug', {
                controller: 'ArticleCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'views/article.html'
            })
            .when('/catalog/:category/:subcategory', {
                controller: 'CatalogCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'views/catalog.html'
            })
            .when('/product/:category/:subcategory/:product', {
                controller: 'ProductPageCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'views/product.html',
                reloadOnSearch: false
            })
            .when('/product/:category/:subcategory/:product/:texture', {
                controller: 'ProductPageCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'views/product.html',
                reloadOnSearch: false
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    }
]);
```

Comment: are you sure you want to keep the `#!` ? - if you want to remove the hash from the url you have to turn on html5mode

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a valid URL - http://domain/#!product

It should be http://domain/#!/product or http://domain/product,

To transform your URLs in desired way, it gives you some heads up - 
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location